# How to add nodes in a polygon in Rive?

Tags: animation, rive

I'm having the following situation: I have a polygon, a path of nodes like that:

[image: my situation]

Now I want to add some more nodes, so edit the polygon. How can I add some nodes in the poligon?

Thank you for your help

I have alrady tryed to open the path at a point like that:

[image: here I already opened the path]

but I wasnt able to add a new node. I tryed by using the pen-tool but it didnt worked out. I was only able to move old nodes around but not to make new onoes.

Also I tryed right clicking on the edge between two nodes, but that also didnt helped.